# ZF2-Form submission without reloading the page in the modal itself as shown in picture

Tags: php, angularjs, zend-framework2

I want to submit this form without reloading the page (inside the modal itself).After validating form it should redirect to the desired page not after form posting.
note:**I do not want to use AJAX**
thank you.
Here is the Image:[image]

here is what i have tried..

```
     public function listAction()
{
    if(!$user = $this->identity())
        return $this->redirect()->toRoute('user',array('action'=>'login'));
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();

    $survey = new Survey();
    $form = new SurveyForm();
    $message="Create Survey";
    $surveyList = $em->getRepository('Easysurvey\Entity\Survey')->findall();

    $form->get('submit')->setValue('Save & Add Question');

    $form->setHydrator(new DoctrineHydrator($em,'Easysurvey\Entity\Survey'));
    $form->bind($survey);

    //add new       
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->isPost()) {
        $data = $request->getPost();

            $form->setInputFilter(new SurveyFilter($this->getServiceLocator()));
            $form->setData($data);

            if ($form->isValid()) {
                $this->prepareData($survey);

                $this->flashMessenger()->addSuccessMessage('succesfully created');
                $em->persist($survey);
                $em->flush();

                    return $this->redirect()->toRoute('survey', array('action' => 'list'));
            }
        }
    }
    return array('form' => $form,
                    'surveyList' => $surveyList,
                        'message' => $message

    );
}
```

list.phtml:

```
                                <!-- Create Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
       <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"><?php echo $message?></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <?php
                $form->setAttribute('action', $this->url('survey', array('action' => 'list')),'class','form-horizontal');
                $form->prepare();

                echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
                echo $this->formHidden($form->get('id'));
                echo $this->formRow($form->get('name'));
                echo '<br />';
                echo $this->formRow($form->get('description'));
                echo '<br />';
                echo $this->formRow($form->get('startdate'));
                echo '<br />';
                echo $this->formRow($form->get('enddate'));
                echo '<br />';
                echo $this->formRow($form->get('createdby'));
                echo '<br />';
                echo $this->formSubmit($form->get('submit'));
                echo $this->form()->closeTag();
            ?>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's great, let us know if you're having any problems with what you've tried.

Comment: When i am hitting the submit button it is redirecting so the modal goes away. i want keep the modal till my form has not validated..

Comment: Show us what you've tried.  SO isn't free work.

Comment: AS you said, i have added the action part.Is anything more required.Actually you did not understand my question.thank you #Daedalus

Comment: I understood it perfectly; you're looking for a way to submit a form so that it adds data somewhere, and then submit that data later using a normal form.  I'm pretty sure that's what you meant, at least.  However, we have a policy here; those with problems in code must post the code in the question.  On top of that, you pretty much were asking for someone to solve the problem for you.  It doesn't work like that here, we want to see what you've tried, where you're having problems.. what did, did not work, etc. <continued>

Comment: <continued> I'd recommend you check out [this article](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/), though the important parts of that article are mainly these bits: In order to give you an answer that works for you, we need to know what you've tried, and why it isn't working for you.  That saves us from giving you solutions that don't fit your circumstances.  You've already supplied one, 'no ajax', but we need more than that.

Comment: Now, onto your question; what you describe is javascript.  Where is your javascript?

Comment: But i am using here a bootstrap modal as i edited the view file(list.phtml),just take a look.

Comment: What you describe is javascript, and yet you have no javascript?  That's where the magic actually happens, and we'll need it to continue.

Comment: But javascript for what for validating form or for showing form.Sorry I did not understand.Just show,is there any way to do without using ajax.

Comment: Javascript, for preventing the form's submit action from taking place, for transferring the data within the form to a temp variable or location, and for later submitting that form through another form, via the dynamic creation of elements or the filling of previously created elements, with that form's action being the page you with to redirect to.  Otherwise, it's impossible and you need ajax.  As to your 'just show' request, I'm not about to write a complete solution for you when you have yet to attempt it yourself.

Comment: Now this was what my question for.Thank you for letting me know about these,specially for that article.I know javascript can do this but how ?

Comment: Your question is tagged angularjs, however I'm not familiar with that library; what I am familiar with however is jQuery, another js library.  The first thing you need to do is find the submit button to the form, or the form in the modal, and prevent the default action of that form.  After that is done, collect the data in the form, and append it as hidden inputs to the form you want to use to redirect the page.  Then, close the modal using whatever js is needed to do so.  From there, figure out how you want to submit the final form, and then do so.

Comment: This can be useful. I will try!
thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need javascript for that, Jquery make ajax calls really simple, basically:

To get the url: $('form.form-horizontal').attr('action');

Then on the callback which is a function called after the request is executed, you hide the bootstrap modal and optionally show a success message to the end user.

[$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: The user stated in their post that ajax is not possible.

Comment: well that's like styling a website without css.

Comment: Not really, not even close.  Either way, it's the OP's requirement.